# Sort array in javascript with quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
var arr = ['hello','"end" two', 'end one', 'yes', 'abc' ];
```

I need to sort it as shown below

```
// abc,  end one, "end" two, hello, yes
```

What should i do?

Comment: "end" two can't comes before end one when you go for order change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could sort with a [`String#localeCompare`'s option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Using_options).

> **`ignorePunctuation`**
>
> Whether punctuation should be ignored. Possible values are `true` and `false`; the default is `false`.

```js
var array = ['hello', '"end" two', 'end one', 'yes', 'abc'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { ignorePunctuation: true });
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Brilliant, you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sortarray(a,b) {
  a = a.replace(/"/g,'');
  b = b.replace(/"/g,'');

    return (a < b ? -1 : 1);
}

keys = ['hello','"end" two', 'end one', 'yes', 'abc' ]

var sorted = keys.sort(sortarray);
alert(sorted);
```

Here is created function which can be used directly where you want.

Comment: @NinaScholz Doesn't it return `-1` or `1`? And I think not returning `0` in case of equality would not compromise the sort. Of course, `localeCompare` is better.

Comment: @torazaburo, right, it does not return zero.

Comment: 1 & -1 are used as compare flags , for reverse order < replaced with > & gives reverse order result.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sortarray(one,two) {
  one = one.replace(/"/g,'');
  two = two.replace(/"/g,'');

    return (one < two ? -1 : 1);
}

keys = ['hello','"end" two', 'end one', 'yes', 'abc' ]

var sorted = keys.sort(sortarray);
alert(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is going to remove quote marks on every single comparison, which could be a problem if there were many items. Instead, create a parallel array of values to be used in sorting:

```
const sortValues = arr.map(elt => elt.replace(/"/g, ''));
```

Now sort a list of numbers starting from 0 according to those values:

```
const sortIndexes = arr.map((_, i) => i)
  .sort((a, b) => sortValues[a].localeCompare(sortValues[b]));
```

Then re-order the input array based on the sorted indices:

```
const result = sortIndexes.map(i => arr[i]);
```